# AD MMC Tools disagree with 'net user' and 'net group'. Which is wrong?

Tags: active-directory

Using the AD MMC snapin, I show that a particular user is a member of a set of groups, but when I use the `net user` and `net groups` utilities, the group membership is different, and more importantly, contradictory.

We're trying to track down a problem that seems to be related to a user not being in the right groups, but the MMC tools says she's in the group and `net user` and `net group` say she's not.  What's going on, and how do we proceed?

Comment: Are you connecting to the same domain controller that you're running the `net` commands against?  Do you have delayed (or messed up) replication?

Comment: One of our domain admins thought to remove her from the group and add her back again and that seems to have worked (still testing it out).

Comment: @ShaneMadden I don't know.  How would I find out?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that on multiple domain controllers?  Are you seeing any other inconsistencies with groups on other users?  If AD is inconsistent, you've got real issues.

Also, have you tried pulling her out of the groups in question, then forcing NTDS replication between the DCs (from Active Directory Sites & Services), then adding her back to the groups, then forcing replication again?

If you force replication, do you see any errors in the Event Logs?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of group is the problem with? Global, Domain Local, Universal?
NET is a very old legacy command and won't work for non Global groups.
Try using the newer DSQUERY tools if the problem is one of the new group types.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725702%28WS.10%29.aspx

Example:

dsquery user -samid THEUSER| dsget user -memberof -expand | dsget group -samid | sort

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although I don't have access to any of the domain controllers (which is presumably where I'd find that utility).

Comment: RSAT http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7887   or Adminpack http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3725  have the dsquery, dsmod, dsget tools